# (Video Included) Addon Wont Activate after Installation

Tags: python, add-on, sapling-addon

I'm trying to enable an addon from a basic python template I saved, but it wont let me check the box to activate it. Here's what the problem looks like:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tGFOwwfikAA&feature=youtu.be

Is there any reason it's not letting me do this? 
Thank you very much for your time!

```
import bpy


def main(context):
    for ob in context.scene.objects:
        print(ob)


class SimpleOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Tooltip"""
    bl_idname = "object.simple_operator"
    bl_label = "Simple Object Operator"

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return context.active_object is not None

    def execute(self, context):
        main(context)
        return {'FINISHED'}

bpy.ops.transform.translate(value=(0, 2.20362, 0), orient_type='GLOBAL', orient_matrix=((1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 1)), orient_matrix_type='GLOBAL', constraint_axis=(False, True, False), mirror=True, proportional='DISABLED', proportional_edit_falloff='SMOOTH', proportional_size=1, release_confirm=True)


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(SimpleOperator)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(SimpleOperator)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()

    # test call
    bpy.ops.object.simple_operator()
```

Comment: Can you include the code or at least the module registration code in your Question? The error message indicates there is a context mismatch i.e. you are doing something in the registration of the module that you should not be.

Comment: Sorry for the ugly formatting. I can't seem to figure out how to put the code in proper format from the 'add-comment' button. Here is the code again by itself.

Comment: bpy.ops.transform.translate(value=(0, -3.05949, 0), orient_type='GLOBAL', orient_matrix=((1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 1)), orient_matrix_type='GLOBAL', constraint_axis=(False, True, False), mirror=True, proportional='DISABLED', proportional_edit_falloff='SMOOTH', proportional_size=1, release_confirm=True)

Comment: It's just code I got from the info window to move the cube left a bit.

Comment: Can you upload the Python file to a pastebin. I really sounds like you have not put the code in the its own function and are instead running it from the module registration which is only supposed to tell Bender it is there.

Comment: Sure, how do I upload a file to the pastebin though?? Sorry, I'm still getting the hang of this forum.

Comment: Edit your original question and paste in your Python then select what you have added and click the button with the two curly braces, this will format the display as code. pastebin.com is a free web site where you can paste in code and have it formatted, all without having to signup

Comment: I tried to do that. Almost worked. It only put some of the code in proper format though. It's just a "simple operator" template, with cube movement code pasted from the info window under the line that says "return finished"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have put your operational code in as part of the **Class SimpleOperator**.

This means that when the **register** creates the **Class** your code is run, which is the wrong time and has no context.

Take the bpy.ops.transform.translate code and move it out of the Class definition and move it into the main function e.g.

```
def main(context):
    for ob in context.scene.objects:
        print(ob)
    bpy.ops.transform.translate(value=(0, 2.20362, 0), orient_type='GLOBAL', orient_matrix=((1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 1)), orient_matrix_type='GLOBAL', constraint_axis=(False, True, False), mirror=True, proportional='DISABLED', proportional_edit_falloff='SMOOTH', proportional_size=1, release_confirm=True)
```

Now when you run the test call

```
bpy.ops.object.simple_operator()
```

It will print out all the Object names and then try and Translate the currently selected Object

Comment: Worth noting, can ditch the main method all together and simply `return bpy.ops.transform.translate(...)` as a one line execute method.  Also the naming convention for 2.8x would suggest this class  be defined as  `class OBJECT_OT_simple_operator(...)`